# Magento is reverting changes

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I find myself doing the same changes on my products again and again. Very often, the same products end up reverting product descriptions to what they where before I changed them, or even keep deactivating themselves.

How can this make any sense?

Comment: Do the updates still exists in the backend of magento? as in if you updated a products description in the magento backend its still there?

Comment: Nope. They're completely gone..

Comment: sounds like an import cron is running somewhere on your system, or a colleague isn't being funny, or you're going nuts, or just ... cache?

Comment: Thanks. What's the easiest way to see all scheduled cron jobs?

Answer (score 2):

**In Magento,product data  does not save  at history**,So if you ***have tried revert back  value of product attribute*** again ***the old once*** then it would  not  be possible.

Once thing you can do, *`create a custom module`* and *`with a db table`*.
And using magento event/observer *`save the  old attribute data's`* at table

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I have not tried to revert anything - but I made a lot of changes in product descriptions yesterday and verified afterwards that everything was changed correctly. When I look at the products to day, maybe half of them has the descriptions they had before I changed them yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is technically not possible - by magento itself, because there is no history, revert or whats'o'ever. When you change something, the old data is gone.

Are you sure it is not your import of product data, a backup or something else which changes this?

Maybe a colleague is changing it?

Firegento wrote a module to monitor all activities in the backend:
[FireGento_AdminMonitoring](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-adminmonitoring)  maybe this helps

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for clarifying that it shouldn't be possible. Is it possible that my dataflow profiles or magmi profiles are running themselves?

Comment: Don't know magmi but afaik is dataflow not automatically run by cron somehow - but it can be configured or implemented of course.

Comment: Thanks. What's the easiest way to see all scheduled cron jobs?